# How to foreach loop and append option in select box ? from jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is data when i do console.log(data.allYear).Data is coming in this form

[image]

And i want to append in this select form like this :

```
<select name="year" id="fiscal_year">
  <option>2018/2019</option>
  <option>2019/2020</option>
  <option>2021/2022</option>
  <option>2022/2023</option>
</select>
```

I am trying with these method but not getting result i want

```
 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filterChartData')
    .then(response => response.json())

    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.allYear)
        data.allYear.forEach(function (fiscalyear) {
            $('#fiscal_year').append('<option >' + fiscalyear + '</option>')
        })
    });
```

Comment: Should it not then be `('<option >' + fiscalyear.year + '</option>')` ? Because currently you are passing the entiry object into the option

Comment: Even I cannot see a id "fiscal_year" in the select definition

Comment: Assuming the fetch works, please untag laravel, click edit and then `[<>]` and post a [mcve] with a relevant object instead of the fetch

Comment: `$('#fiscal_year').append(Object.keys(data.allYear).map(fiscalYear => \`<option>${fiscalyear}</option>\`).join(""))` would work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data.allYear` is an object and not an array, `data.allYear.forEach()` will not work as you expected it to be. What you want is to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead, which returns an array of keys in the object, and then chain `.forEach()` to it, so that you can iterate through all the keys in the object:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/filterChartData')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    Object.keys(data.allYear).forEach(fiscalYear => {
        $('#fiscal_year').append('<option>' + fiscalyear + '</option>')
    });
});
```

Comment: or much better for performance: `$('#fiscal_year').append(Object.keys(data.allYear).map(fiscalYear => \`<option>${fiscalyear}</option>\`).join(""))`

Answer (score 1):

user JSON.parse to parse the resoponse data and try

`JSON.parse(data.allYear).forEach(fiscalYear => { $('#fiscal_year').append('<option>' + fiscalyear + '</option>')    })`